# How can I use VS2017 with Unity 2018

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm new with Unity and I have problem with target .Net Framework version in the project. Visual Studio shows me this message …

[image: error screenshot]

… but I already have .Net framework 3.5 installed. What can I do?

Message:

> The C# Project "Assembly-CSharp" is targetting ".NET Framework, Version=v3.5", which is not installed on this machine. To proceed, select an option below.
>
> - Change the target to .Net Framework 4.6.1
> - Download the targeting pack for ".Net Framework, Version=v3.5"
> - Do not load the project

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't choose the second option and click OK? Did doing that fix the problem?

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: That is quite odd. You definitely clicked OK, installed the targetting pack, rebooted the machine and tried again?

Comment: can you add the message written into your post instead of a picture. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I click OK, it redirects me to microsoft.com, but there are only .NET Framework 4.5.2 and higher there. So I installed 3.5 from Visual Studio Installer and rebooted the computer, but the message is still here

Answer (score 0):

I faced this before. You can download targeting pack for developer from microsoft. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix!
go to this directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework

Then create a folder named 4.6.1

Copy all files from 3.5 folder
Paste them all in 4.6.1 folder
Done!